# show tooltip in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I show a specific color for the different types of data and the right side of highstock.

For example if you look at [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) it has Tokyo, New York etc shown at the right side of chart.

I wanted to do this with highstock and compare charts series
   http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

Answer (score 0):

use this code before creating Chart. Specify your colors in sequence.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['red', 'green', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']
    });
```

Here is working fiddle `[`http://jsfiddle.net/sjpfLz8r/`][1]`

Comment: I need to show these colours in highstocks not in highcharts

Comment: do u have any idea about that

Comment: When you set it in highstock, colors will also be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly enable the [`legend`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#legend.enabled) in highstock. Then you can format it how you want (which side to put it on, etc).

```
legend: {
    enabled: true
}
```

To enable the [`marker`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.marker), which is disabled by default in highstock, you need to explicitly set it:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        compare: 'percent',
        marker: {
            enabled: true,
            radius: 4
        }
    }
}
```

This will show the marker on the data as well as in the legend.

Comment: I dn't wanted to change its side i wanted to have it as a static for my data so that the user always know which color is representing wt instead of knowing by hovering

Comment: I do not know what you mean. A legend is static. Do you want the legend in the same place as your demo link? If so you need to adjust its position as the default is on the bottom.

Comment: are u able to see the side symbols in that ??show n for tokyo a blue symbol ,orange for london ?i need like that in highstocks http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare .do u see anything in this no? i want in this :(

Comment: user3929413 you need to enable the marker. Please check out those links I am posting that go to the API documentation.